# dropboxdownloads.com - scam or legit?

Tags: dropbox, phishing

I've just gotten an email directing me to dropboxdownloads.com, since I have "received a secure document". As the email has no clear identifying personal details of mine, nor any information about the supposed sender, I'm worried this is a scam.

When I visit that website, it offers me a download of a .doc file - super fishy, since I haven't even entered the document access key. I know .doc file can theoretically contain viruses, macros which executed on document load or whatever (even though I'm not on Windows) so I've refrained from opening it.

My guess that this is a scam, but - could I be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I opened the .doc file with Libreoffice, and a security setting of not executing macros automatically.

It contained a generic-looking single page promotional for "Dropbox Business" - and macros.

So yeah, this looks like some sort of a scam - although possibly not a virus.